# Multiple absolute values with multiple variables in an LP

Tags: linear-programming, linearization, absolute-value

Assume that we have a LP with the constraint
$$ \sum_{j} \left(c_j x_j + |c_j x_j - \alpha_j + \beta_j|\right) \leq y  $$
and

$$\alpha_j + \beta_j \leq \lambda_j  $$
for all $j$, where the (positive) cost vector $c$ is known, $x_j, \alpha_j$, and $\beta_j \geq 0$ are variables. How do i linearize the absolute values, the usual trick with $|f(x)| \leq y$ would not work because we have multiple absolute values and multiple variables inside the absolute values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the usual technique applies.  Introduce a variable $z_j$ (together with linear constraints) to represent the absolute value, and replace the original constraint with $\sum_j (c_j x_j + z_j) \le y$.

Comment: The constraint $\alpha_j + \beta_j \leq \lambda_j$ below remains the same right ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.